# sameperiodlastyear when fiscal calendar is not month to month

Tags: powerbi-desktop

Is there a way to use the SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR function in Power BI when your fiscal calendar does not go month to month? Our monthly calendar ends on the last Saturday of the month. This is what I have

```
Current = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('FactWholesale'))
Last = CALCULATE([Current],SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(DimDate[Date]))
```

the Current months  are always correct. an example
the current September 2017 is 594 and current month September 2018 is 578
the problem is sameperiodlastyear for September 2018 is 579 and it should be 594.
I believe what is happening is to figure sameperiodlastyear it is using 8/27/2017 - 9/30/2017 to figure.  is there a way to make this work?

```
FiscalMonthStartDate    FiscalMonthEndDate  FiscalMonth
8/28/2016   10/1/2016   Sep-17
8/27/2017   9/30/2017   Sep-18
```